# How to subtract today's date with an input date?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

My current code:

```
import datetime
from time import strptime
leapyear = 0

isValid = False
while not isValid:
     in_date = input(" Please in put a year in the format dd/mm/yyyy ")
     try:
         d = strptime(in_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
         isValid=True
     except:
         print ("This is not in the right format")

diff = d -datetime.date.today()
print(in_date)
print(d)
print(diff)
```

I cannot subtract the two dates, the input date and today's date from each other. It throws a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'datetime.date'` exception.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module objects only support subtraction with other objects from the same library. The `time` module `struct_time` tuple is not one of those.

Use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the date instead:

```
 d = datetime.datetime.strptime(in_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

then use the [`datetime.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to extract *just* a `date` object from the result:

```
diff = d.date() - datetime.date.today()
```

The result is a [`datetime.timedelta` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Don't catch *all* exceptions; catch just those thrown by `strptime()` when passed a string that doesn't match the expected format, `ValueError`:

```
while True:
     in_date = input(" Please in put a year in the format dd/mm/yyyy ")
     try:
         d = datetime.datetime.strptime(in_date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
         break
     except ValueError:
         print ("This is not in the right format")
```

I used `break` here to end the `while` loop rather than use a flag variable.

Comment: After getting the days how i can i get the return into a dd/mm/yyy format ?

Comment: @user3077551: define 'months' in terms of a difference here.

Comment: @user3077551: see [calculate the difference between two datetime.date() dates in years and months](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12564077)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from datetime import strptime
currentdate=datetime.date.today()
date_str = input("enter date in format dd/mm/yyy") #inputed date is in string need to conver ot into date 
#format_str = '%d/%m/%Y' # The format
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y') # convert inputed date into date 
diff= datetime_obj.date() - currentdate # take .date because we only need date not time 

print("Current date ==",currentdate)
print("entered date ==",datetime_obj.date()) 
print("remaining Days left  ===",diff)
```