# How to find the difference between two dates in years

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have two columns in my dataframe that I have converted into datetime. I'm trying to subtract these numbers and find the difference in years. This is the code I'm using:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
difference_in_years = relativedelta(x['start'], x['end']).year
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the issue?

Comment: what is `x[start]`, x`[end]` type

Comment: They both got type '<M8[ns]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute `.years` with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2015-10-02','2014-11-05'],
                   'end':['2018-01-02','2018-10-05']})

df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['y'] = df.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x['end'], x['start']).years, axis=1)
```

Or use `list comprehension`:

```
df['y'] = [relativedelta(i, j).years for i, j in zip(df['end'], df['start'])]
```

---

```
print (df)
       start        end  y
0 2015-10-02 2018-01-02  2
1 2014-11-05 2018-10-05  3
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2015-10-02','2014-11-05'],
                   'end':['2018-01-02',np.nan]})

df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

m = df[['start','end']].notnull().all(axis=1)
df.loc[m, 'y'] = df[m].apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x['end'], x['start']).years, axis=1)
print (df)
       start        end    y
0 2015-10-02 2018-01-02  2.0
1 2014-11-05        NaT  NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error AssertionError: occurred at index 0. Is it because I have some NaT values?

Comment: @H.Z. - Yes, it is possible. Check edit - filter only non NaNs rows in both datetimes columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
(df['end'] - df['start'])/pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')
```

and round the result if needed.

In pandas `v0.23.4` and later you can do

```
(df['end'] - df['start'])//pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')
```

to get whole year difference straight away.

Update: In panda `v0.25` and later, `pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')` is not supported, because a year is not a consistent unit of measure (sometimes 365d, sometimes 366d). You can do this instead if the 365d approximation is acceptable:

```py
(df['end'] - df['start'])/pd.Timedelta(365, 'D')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide a `timedelta` series by year units and, if necessary, round:

```
# data from jezrael

df['years'] = (df['end'] - df['start']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
df['years_floor'] = df['years'].round()

print(df)

       start        end     years  years_floor
0 2015-10-02 2018-01-02  2.253297          2.0
1 2014-11-05        NaT       NaN          NaN
```

Comment: pandas also has timedelta: 

`df['years'] = (df['end'] - df['start']) / pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas.Timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [calculate the difference between two datetime.date() dates in years and months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564077/calculate-the-difference-between-two-datetime-date-dates-in-years-and-months)

```
from dateutil import relativedelta as rdelta
from datetime import date
d1 = date(2001,5,1)
d2 = date(2012,1,1)
rd = rdelta.relativedelta(d2,d1)
rd
relativedelta(years=+10, months=+8)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if d1 and d2 are pandas series containing dates.